# Passing both user ID and product ID to Paypal Button

Tags: reactjs, django, paypal

I am using `@paypal/react-paypal-js` to display the PayPal button and create an order. I am specifically interested in processing credit card payments. Once my Django backend receives the payment capture completion event from PayPal, it needs to store information about a particular user owning a particular product. Hence, the notification has to contain both the user ID (i.e. email) and the product ID.

This is how I am trying to pass these two pieces of information in my frontend:

```
createOrder={(data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
            {
                amount: {
                    value: course.price,
                    currency_code: course.currency,
                },
                custom_id: course.title,
            },
        ],
        payer: {
            email_address: userEmail,
        }
    });
}}
```

Here is my `onApprove`:

```
onApprove={(data, actions) => onSuccess(data, actions)}
```

where `onSuccess` is implemented as follows:

```
const onSuccess= (data, actions) => {
    return actions.order.capture().then(
        function (details) {
            toast.success('Payment completed. Thank you, ' + 
                          details.payer.name.given_name,
                          {duration: 6000})
        }
    );
}
```

The user email address is automatically filled into the form. However, the `webhook_event` event in the server does not contain this information. That is, there is no `payer` field inside `resource` in `webhook_event`.

I also tried adding `payee: {email_address: userEmail}` into `purchase_units`, but then there was no option to pay with credit card after pressing on the PayPal button. That option got replaced by the option to create a PayPal account.

How can I pass the two pieces of information so as to get them in `webhook_event`? (I would like to avoid the ugly solution of concatenating both pieces into `custom_id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried adding payee: {email_address: userEmail} into purchase_units, but then there was no option to pay with credit card after pressing on the PayPal button. That option got replaced by the option to create a PayPal account.

`payee` sets which account *receives* the PayPal payment. The black Debit or Credit Card button will generally be available for guest payments if the recipient PayPal account exists and is confirmed.

> How can I pass the two pieces of information so as to get them in webhook_event?

If you absolutely must store two pieces information as part of a custom value (usually only useful for subscriptions, although even for subscriptions there are better solutions that involve using your own database), you could encode a JSON object with `json.dumps({'email': somevalue, 'product': somevalue}` and store that json string value in custom_id -- then decode it later on receipt with `json.loads`.

It's unusual to need to do anything like this, however, especially for one-time Order payments. You should implement order creation and capture from your own server routes and store the necessary information on your own database immediately on successful capture, before returning the capture result to the button JavaScript.  See the information for a server integration in [Set up standard payments.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/)

Webhooks are not necessary at all in such a case, much less retrieving item information from a webhook. You however can and should include item information as part of the PayPal transaction for informational purposes, via an `items` array. This will also show to the payer in the upper right cart dropdown during checkout, and be visible in the completed paypal.com transaction details.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the confusion about `payee`. I do call `actions.order.capture()` when handling `onApprove` (as now shown in the question). Do you mean that I should send the details of the purchase from there instead of relying on the webhook to send these details? But isn't that opening a security hole, whereby a malicious user can fake my client to make my server think that he purchased something when he did not? Also, how would I know that the payment capture for *this* order is complete?

Comment: The above details what you should do instead, beginning in the third paragraph, "You should implement order creation and capture from your own server routes..", so I"ll refer you to what's there.

Comment: You wrote that what you suggested in the second paragraph was only necessary for subscriptions. I did not understand what you meant by "implement order creation and capture from your own server routes and store the necessary information on your own database immediately on successful capture" in the third paragraph. My comment is trying to make sure that I understood you correctly and that your suggestion makes sense from the security point of view, especially since you wrote in the final paragraph that webhooks are  unnecessary.

Comment: Webhooks are unnecessary if you implement creating and capturing an order from your server. This does not apply to subscriptions. Find the guide for a server integration and link to demo code within 'Set up standard payments', https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/ .